# VBA Form disappearing

Tags: excel, user-interface, vba, mode

I have a VBA form that when I click on it, performs some long calculations (a few seconds to several seconds long) and then displays the results on frames in the form. However, once every so often, the form hides on me and I need to click around to the VBA editor and back to the sheet to make it display again

I have

```
Me.Repaint
```

at the end of the calculations on the form
but it still doesn't help

I also tried disabling the "EnableCalculation" attribute of the main sheet, but still no use

Anyone ever run into something like this? Do I need to load the form in some special way?

Comment: Consider adding `DoEvents()` to your code. If you have a loop that executes many times, try putting DoEvents() just before the `Next` statement.

Comment: Why haven't you accepted more answers?

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem. When saving an Excel workbook by clicking on a command button on a modeless Userform, the form disappears as the code completes.

I read that the problem was due to some inter-compatible changes that Microsoft has made and found some very elaborate solutions involving a lot of complex code that I was unable to integrate into my project. However, I did find a very quick workaround.

In my case the Userform only disappeared when the code executed the `End Sub` command of the command button's code. I simply added an `Exit Sub` immediately before it and the Userform no longer disappears.

Comment: I have not found this to consistently work - especially when my code is using ADO against a slow Oracle data warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning off and on screen updating so Excel is not redrawing the screen with each change.

```
sub doSomthing()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'do something
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The form disappears because Microsoft has changed the model by which forms are owned by a 'superior' process (Excel in your case).  I have the same problem and also cannot overcome it.

Just sit tight until Microsoft decides that it is worth their effort to fix yet another introduced and untested problem by making changes to something that already worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a side effect of the SDI (Single Document Interface) that was introduced with Excel 2013. The various suggestions that invoke DoEvents, ScreenUpdating, etc. may help in certain scenarios, but they do not cure the behavior.

There is a full solution posted here: [Keeping Userforms on top of SDI windows in Excel 2013 and up](https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/keepuserformontop02.asp)

If that is too involved for your needs, a quick-and-dirty solution is to minimize and restore the active window, which forces the userform back on top of the stack.

```
'Do long-winded process first, then:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This doesn't prevent the form from disappearing, but it makes it reappear the end of the process.

Comment: only solution which worked for me. After clicking a CommandButton an data import is being triggered via PowerQuery and after that my UserForm disappeared somewhat. That workaround brings it to the foreground again. Nothing else worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with the following two lines of code instead of the repaint.

```
Me.Show
```

And/Or:

```
Me.SetFocus
```

Hopefully, one of these will work for you!

Comment: sorry I didn't reply for so long I thought those would help, but now me.show crashes me.setFocus doesn't work the screen updating doesn't cut it either doEvents didn't help, but it DID help me withsomething else, so thanks still, any ideas? thanks everyone for the input

Comment: You'll need to show more of your code for us to see what is happening. Ideally with a section (that you've narrowed it down to via troubleshooting) that is running when it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use all these to make it happen. (frmGUI is my form)
DoEvents
frmGUI.Repaint
frmGUI.Show

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

With Office 2013 and Windows 7, simply adding `DoEvents` right before the end of the `sub` (where the form disappeared) kept the form open. Nothing else needed....for my situation.